# Arduino/Wokwi buzzer activates on digitalWrite(LOW) too

Tags: arduino, gyroscope, arduino-esp32

I am trying to make a buzzer play when the gyroscope attached to the Arduino passes a certain rotation threshold on the x axis. The problem is: it also activates when I simulate to go back **under** the threshold, which is quite strange.

```
#include <Adafruit_MPU6050.h>
#include <CuteBuzzerSounds.h>

int buzzer_pin = 4;
Adafruit_MPU6050 IMU;

void setup() {
  pinMode(buzzer_pin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200); // Any baud rate should work
  digitalWrite(buzzer_pin, LOW);

  if (!IMU.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Sensor init failed");
    while (1)
      yield();
  }
  Serial.println("Found a sensor");
  IMU.setAccelerometerRange(MPU6050_RANGE_2_G);
  switch (IMU.getAccelerometerRange()) {
    case MPU6050_RANGE_2_G:
      Serial.print("+-2G");
      break;
  }
  IMU.setGyroRange(MPU6050_RANGE_250_DEG);
  switch (IMU.getGyroRange()) {
    case MPU6050_RANGE_250_DEG:
      Serial.print("+- 250 deg/s");
      break;
  }
}

void loop() {
  sensors_event_t acc, giro, t;
  IMU.getEvent(&acc, &giro, &t);
  Serial.print("\n X: ");
  Serial.print(giro.gyro.x, 1);
  Serial.print(" Y: ");
  Serial.print(giro.gyro.y, 1);
  Serial.print(" Z: ");
  Serial.print(giro.gyro.z, 1);

  if (giro.gyro.x > 0.5) //threshold
  {
    digitalWrite(buzzer_pin, HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(buzzer_pin, LOW);
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

A link to try it out: https://wokwi.com/projects/351917249533051471

The threshold is between 25 and 30 degrees: to simulate it, click on the IMU and play with the rotation X slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood the problem:

in Wokwi, buzzers do "activate" (show notes but don't make any real sound) when using `DigitalWrite()` but they are not made to activate with that. One should use `tone()` as by documentation.